# ajax update qty where id and qty

Tags: php, ajax

i am trying to update quantity in a cart where there are multiple items,

for example -

```
var get id of order item
var get quantity
post both to updateqty.php
```

with multiple lines on order there are multiple textboxes with the id of qty and multiple hidden inputs with the id of part so it will only work on the first id that it finds on that page, i need it to be able to update other items in the order,

so for example

```
get class of the textbox, then find out which qty is being updated, then update the quantity of the item.
```

if anyone has an idea how this can be done it would be appreciated.

```
<script>


function updateqty() {
    var ud_first = document.getElementById('part').value;
    var ud_last = document.getElementById('qty').value;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("cart").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "php/updateqty.php?order=<?php echo $order; ?>&id=" + ud_first + "&qty="+ud_last, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
<?php 


$sql="SELECT * FROM `orders` WHERE  `invoice` = '".$order."' ORDER BY id DESC";

$result = mysql_query($sql);
echo"
     <table id='POITable' width='100%' border='1'>
        <tr>
            <td>SKU</td>
            <td>QTY</td>
            <td width='45%'>item</td>
            <td>Unit Price</td>
            <td>Line Price</td>
            <td>Delete</td>
        </tr>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
echo"<tr><td>" . $row['part'] . "</td><td><form name='test'>
   <input type='hidden' value='" . $row[id] . "' id='part'>   <input type='text' id='qty' value='" . $row['qty'] . "' onblur='updateqty(this.id)'></form></td><td>" . $row['description'] . "</td><td>" . $row['price'] . "</td><td>" . $row['lineprice'] . "</td><td> <input type='image' src='images/btn_delete.png' value='" . $row[id] . "' onclick='deletesku(this.value)' height='30'/></td>
";

 }
?>
```

the insert php is

```
$id=$_GET[id];

$sql2="SELECT * FROM  `orders` WHERE  `id` = '".$id."'";

$result2 = mysql_query($sql2);

$row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2);

$order=$_GET[order];
$qty=$_GET[qty];

$sql="SELECT * FROM  `stock` WHERE  `part` = '".$part."'";

$result = mysql_query($sql);

$row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result);

$lineprice=$qty * $row2[price];

$sqlins1 = "UPDATE `orders` SET qty='$qty', lineprice='$lineprice' WHERE id = '".$id."'";
```

it is ids in the html that there are multiples of NOT THE MYSQL TABLE

so i need it to pick up the id of a product in the cart and update the quantity of that id by ajax

the impotant bits of the script are

```
    function updateqty() {
        var ud_first = document.getElementById('part').value;
        var ud_last = document.getElementById('qty').value;

        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("cart").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "php/updateqty.php?order=<?php echo $order; ?>&id=" + ud_first + "&qty="+ud_last, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
    </script>
    <?php 


    $sql="SELECT * FROM `orders` WHERE  `invoice` = '".$order."' ORDER BY id DESC";

    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
      {
    echo"<tr><td>" . $row['part'] . "</td>

<td>

    <form name='test'>
           <input type='hidden' value='" . $row[id] . "' id='part'>
       <input type='text' id='qty' value='" . $row['qty'] . "' onblur='updateqty(this.id)'></form>

    </td><td>" . $row['description'] . "</td><td>" . $row['price'] . "</td><td>" . $row['lineprice'] . "</td><td> <input type='image' src='images/btn_delete.png' value='" . $row[id] . "' onclick='deletesku(this.value)' height='30'/></td>
        ";

         }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
    function updateqty() {  

    var str="$(this).attr('name')"; 
    var orderCode=str.slice(9,-1);
    var quantity = $(this).value;  

          if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
    else
      {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {

    xmlhttp.open("GET","updateqty.php?order=<?php echo $order; ?>&id=" + orderCode + "&qty=" + quantity,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    }

    </script>


    <div id="cart">
    <?php
    $sql="SELECT * FROM `orders` WHERE  `invoice` = '".$order."' ORDER BY id DESC";

    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    echo"
       <table id='POITable' width='100%' border='1'>
            <tr>
                <td>SKU</td>
                <td>QTY</td>
                <td width='45%'>item</td>
                <td>Unit Price</td>
                <td>Line Price</td>
                <td>Delete</td>
            </tr>";
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
      {
    echo"<tr><td>" . $row['part'] . "</td><td>
    <input type='text' name='quantity[779]' size='3' value='" . $row['qty'] . "' tabindex='1' onblur='updateqty(this.value)' />

</td><td>" . $row['description'] . "</td><td>" . $row['price'] . "</td><td>" . $row['lineprice'] . "</td><td><img src='images/btn_delete.png' onclick='deleteRow(this)' height='30'/></td>
";
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

So you are saying you are having thouble with an SQL Update statement? If you want help at least show us the SQL query. The SELECT statement is no use since the UPDATE is whats broken. 
Also SQL UPDATE statements are incredibly simple to execute if you are having trouble it's because you have done 0 research.

I will try to help you somewhat with the limited amount of code you have provided. An update should look something like this

```
UPDATE <tablename> SET QTY=$qty AND SKU=$sku WHERE id=$id
```

If you are creating a cart you will need more than the quantity to be stored. you cant just have a cart with 6 qty in it and no way to know what the qty is. I suggest you create a table that contains user id and item id and quantity. then when the person adds to cart insert a new row that contains the user id the item id and the quantity. Then when the user goes to the cart you can call the items table using the item id to get all the info you need about the item such as cost etc.

Comment: sorry the update is in another file i will put that in the question now for you, the insert part works fine though

Comment: updateqty.php?order=<?php echo $order; ?>&qty="+str is the problem. It is only passing 2 header variables where as the script is using 3. the update needs an id (primary key) which you are getting from $id=$_GET[id]; but you arent passing an id in the header so it never gets assigned

Comment: it needs to pick up the id but all the ids are the same so i need it to tell the insert script which line to update by which text box is changed

Comment: all sql tables NEED a primary key. A table with duplicate keys means you cant update it. You need to redesign this entire thing. I suggest you do it out on paper and draw lines between the primary and foreign keys. If you dont know what a foreign key is then google it. Tables need primary keys and thats that. If you want to update table where id = 10 and there are 50 rows where id = 10 then how is the system meant to know what row?
userid + itemid = these 2 columns make up the primary key and then a qty column. there will never be 2 rows with the same user id and item id

Comment: well as i stated before you are not passing 3 variables in the header but the php file is looking for 3 header variables. $id=$_GET[id]; since $_get['id'] does not exist it will = nothing. then when the query executes it will say where id = nothing and nothing cant be a primary key so it breaks. you say all the ids are the same and then i said you cant have multiple primary keys...i fail to see how this isnt a database design issue

Comment: this updates the quantity and works fine but it will only work on the first item on the list because it gets the element by id where there are lots of text boxes with the id qty it cannot see the 2nd ,3rd and 4th input with that id

Comment: it isnt anything to do with database it is the fact that there are multiple html text boxes with the same id

Comment: UPDATE `orders` SET qty='$qty', lineprice='$lineprice' WHERE id = '".$id."'"

$id is never given a value

Comment: hmm ok so. well first those text boxes need different ids. make the id of each text box the id (primar key) of the row in the db. If all those text boxes have the same id like you say they do then that means when the query gets executed that they are all updating the same box. Get the id from php when you query the db to get the shopping cart items. (i dont think you have a primary key but you say you do so if you do the id in the query needs to be that primary key value) updateqty.php?order=<?php echo $order; ?>&id=" + <?php <row id taken from db>?> + "&qty="+ud_last