# ajax doesnt pass variable to php script

Tags: javascript, ajax

Hi i cant get this script to work the update script works fine but this doesnt seem to pass any variables to the update qty page

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

function updateqty() {

   var str = $(this).attr('name'); 
   var orderCode = str.slice(9, -1);
   var quantity = $(this).value; 
   var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); 

   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() 
   {
      xmlhttp.open("GET","updateqty.php?id=" + orderCode + "&qty=" + quantity, true);
      xmlhttp.send();
   }
}

</script>

<input type='text' name='quantity[701]' size='3' tabindex='1' onblur='updateqty(this)' />
```

Comment: any reason why you aren't using good ol' jquery ajax?

Comment: Your code seems to be incomplete. It's not really possible to help you in this case.

Comment: i have only left script relevent to the issue, i need the name '701' and value of the input to be sent to updateqty.php via ajax

Comment: Why are there quotes around `"$(this).attr('name')"`?  It seems like the `str` variable would contain that instead of `quantity[701]`, which is what you want.

Comment: i have tried with and without "", i am new to ajax and javascript

Comment: Joe, you appear to have multiple accounts, as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16508278/ajax-update-qty-where-id-and-qty?rq=1 was asked in a very similar manner, with the same syntax. Only use one account

Comment: This only needs to work in google chrome app mode, doesnt need to be cross browser compatible

Answer (score 2):

You might want to define xmlhttp. They're not reusable, after all.

```
 var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
```

This will not be cross-browser compliant as it will fail on old IE. You're using jQuery for the name selection - why don't you make use of `jQuery.ajax`?